# Unwanted Line in Tikz Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made a study guide for my students (we are studying rational functions) and when creating a key that involves graphs, I am getting a strange error. In my graph, there is an unwanted line at `y=-1` but I don't see anything in my tex code that would create it. Can anyone explain to me what is going on?

While I'm here, I have 2 other questions to tidy up the graph

1. How would I have tikz display every other label for a tick on the axis? For example, listing all of `-9,...,9` creates a lot of clutter on the graph and listing `-9,-7,...,9` would make it easier to read.
2. Is there a neat way to create dashed asymptote lines? I can create them but they don't look neat at all.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, colonequals, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs, amscd, pgfplots, multicol, geometry}

\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={axis x line=middle, axis y line=middle, xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis equal }}

\geometry{textwidth=6.3in,textheight=9in}

\parindent=0in
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Find \textbf{all} intercepts and asymptotes of \(F(x)=\frac{2x^2+16x-18}{x^2+x-6}\) and sketch a graph of \(F(x)\).\\

\(x\)-intercepts: \((-9,0), (1,0)\)\hspace{1cm} \(y\)-intercept: \((0,3)\)\hspace{1cm} VA: \(x=-3,2\)\hspace{1cm} HA: \(y=2\)

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[my style, xtick={-9,-8,...,9}, ytick={-6,-5,...,6},xmin=-10, xmax=10,  ymin=-7, ymax=7]
\addplot[domain=-9.1:-3.1,samples=256] {(2*x^2+16*x-18)/(x^2+x-6)};
\addplot[domain=-2.9:1.9,samples=256] {(2*x^2+16*x-18)/(x^2+x-6)};
\addplot[domain=2.1:9.1,samples=256] {(2*x^2+16*x-18)/(x^2+x-6)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. Most likely the `problem` environment is defined in the `notestpoints` file, which seems to be nonstandard. Could you please cook down you MWE to something that does not rely on files others don't possess? And may it be that your unwanted signs is just the - signs of the negative x coordinates?

Comment: You actually wrote the answer to one of your questions in the question: `xtick={-9,-7,...,9}`.  I don't see any line at y=-1, but the minus signs are almost next to each other, as marmot mentioned.

Comment: Are you still wondering about this? If so, can you modify your example so that it doesn't rely on files we don't have access to (`notestpoints.tex`), and perhaps show an image of that line at y = -1 you're referring to.

Comment: I updated the code and after zooming in see that is what is going on for the "line" I was seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two slightly different versions of the diagram are shown below.

Regarding the asymptotes, a dashed line is a dashed line, it's not really clear to me in what sense the ones you made are "not neat". Anyways, you can draw a dashed line between the axis limits using

```
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
               (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});
```

where `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}` is a way of accessing the lower limit of the axis, thus not having to explicitly write it. Similar for `ymax`, `xmin`, `xmax`. The coordinate "prefix" `axis cs:` is required because `pgfplots` doesn't use axis coordinates for `\draw` etc. *unless* you have `compat=1.11` (or a newer version) in the `\pgfplotsset` in the preamble (see [Why is tikzpicture destroyed when it is added inside the documentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404400/why-is-tikzpicture-destroyed-when-it-is-added-inside-the-documentation/404401#404401)).

In the first of the diagrams below I added nodes/pins to the asymptotes, to indicate the values, mostly needed because I used a wider domain for the function. (Just a thought, which you can ignore as you see fit.) The number used for the pins, e.g. `200` in `pin={200:$x=-3$}`, is an angle, it indicates the direction of the `pin`.

For the tick locations, when you do `a,b,...,c`, the step used to fill in the rest of the series is defined by `b-a`, so as mentioned elsewhere, use `xtick={-9,-7,...,9}` to get x-ticks as you indicated.

Other things: `declare function` is handy for cases where you need to use the same function several times, and if you want to use the same number of samples for all plots, it's more convenient to set it in the `axis` options. Never use `\\` to end a paragraph. I added the `parskip` package instead of just setting the `\parindent` to zero.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{
  amsfonts,
  colonequals,
  amsthm,
  amsmath,
  amssymb,
  mathrsfs,
  amscd,
  pgfplots,
  multicol,
  geometry
}

\pgfplotsset{
  my style/.append style={
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    axis equal
  }
}

\geometry{textwidth=6.3in,textheight=9in}

\usepackage{parskip} % better than just setting zero parindent

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Find \emph{all} intercepts and asymptotes of \(F(x)=\frac{2x^2+16x-18}{x^2+x-6}\) and sketch a graph of \(F(x)\).

\(x\)-intercepts: \((-9,0), (1,0)\)\hfill
\(y\)-intercept: \((0,3)\) \hfill
VA: \(x=-3,2\)\hfill
HA: \(y=2\)

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={F(\x)=(2*\x^2+16*\x-18)/(\x^2+\x-6);},
  every pin edge/.append style={solid} % otherwise the pin edges are dashed
]
\begin{axis}[
  my style,
  xmin=-15, xmax=15,
  ymin=-7, ymax=7,
  clip mode=individual,
  samples=50
]
\addplot[domain=-15:-3.1] {F(x)};
\addplot[domain=-2.9:1.9] {F(x)};
\addplot[domain=2.1:15] {F(x)};

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
               (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
          coordinate[pos=0.9,pin={200:$x=-3$}](a);
\draw [dashed] (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
               (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}) 
          coordinate[pos=0.9,pin={20:$x=2$}](a);

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},2) -- 
               (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},2) node[right]{$y=2$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={F(\x)=(2*\x^2+16*\x-18)/(\x^2+\x-6);},
]
\begin{axis}[
  my style,
  xtick={-9,-7,...,9},
  ytick={-6,-4,...,6},
  xmin=-10, xmax=10,
  ymin=-7, ymax=7,
  clip mode=individual,
  samples=50
]
\addplot[domain=-9.1:-3.1] {F(x)};
\addplot[domain=-2.9:1.9] {F(x)};
\addplot[domain=2.1:9.1] {F(x)};

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
               (axis cs:-3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}) -- 
               (axis cs:2,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}); 

\draw [dashed] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},2) -- 
               (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},2);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: diagrams produced by code]

Comment: By neat I meant it wasn't as simple as typing something like "draw x=1[dashed]" but your solution is simple enough and more importantly explains how to edit and use the commands you have given. Thanks!