# Why is tikzpicture destroyed when it is added inside the documentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a simple drawing via Tikz. The picture in the standalone mode is

[image]

But when I add it inside the documentation as script not pdf or image, the output is

[image]

It is messed up. I'm not sure what may yield this kind of problems. Any suggestions?

This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-8, xmax=10,ymin=-8, ymax=30,axis lines=middle,very thick,ticks=none,xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]  
\addplot[samples=100, domain=-8:4] {5*x}   node[left]{$y_2$}; 
\addplot[samples=50, domain=-8:4]  {2*x+5} node[right]{$y_1$}; 
\draw [thick] (axis cs: 2.2,11) to[bend right] node[scale=.8,above,xshift=-2mm]{$a$} (1,7) ;
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm guessing you had `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or a higher `compat` version in the `standalone` file. With that setting, `axis cs:` is the default, so you don't have to use it for all your coordinates.

In your code you use `axis cs:` for the first coordinate in the `\draw`, but not in the second.

Add a `compat` setting of 1.11 or higher in the preamble, or add `axis cs:` to the second coordinate.

Note also that using 100 samples for a linear function is sort of pointless, 2 is enough.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-8, xmax=10,ymin=-8, ymax=30,axis lines=middle,very thick,ticks=none,xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]  
\addplot[samples=100, domain=-8:4] {5*x}   node[left]{$y_2$}; 
\addplot[samples=50, domain=-8:4]  {2*x+5} node[right]{$y_1$}; 
\draw [thick] (axis cs: 2.2,11) to[bend right] node[scale=.8,above,xshift=-2mm]{$a$} (axis cs:1,7) ; % <--- added axis cs:
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

For fun, a different method for indicating an angle is shown below, using a couple of named coordinates, the `intersections` library to find the intersection, and the `angles` and `quotes` library to draw the angle.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
   xmin=-8, xmax=10,
   ymin=-8, ymax=30,
   axis lines=middle,
   very thick,
   ticks=none,
   xlabel=$x$,
   ylabel=$y$
]  
\addplot[name path=a,samples=2, domain=-8:4] {5*x}   coordinate[label=left:$y_2$] (y2); 
\addplot[name path=b,samples=2, domain=-8:4]  {2*x+5} coordinate[pos=0] (y1) node[right]{$y_1$}; 
\draw [name intersections={of=a and b,by={o}}]
    pic[draw,angle radius=4mm,angle eccentricity=1.3,"$a$"] {angle=y2--o--y1};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I got this error `Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, 'compat=1.15' is unknown in this context. Please use at most 'compat=1.14'. \pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` Using 1.14 didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Oops, I've forgotten to add `axis cs:` in the second coordinate which solved the problem. The code worked without adding `\pgfplotsset` though. Thank you.

Comment: @CroCo Your code works for me if I add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` (or 1.12, 1.13, 1.14 or 1.15). But without that setting, you must specify `axis cs:` in coordinates used by `\draw` etc. As I said, with that setting `axis cs:` is the default.